# Can not pass data to next ViewController depends on UIPickerView textField.text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uipickerview

When I am selecting Target 2 in picker view all working good, the labels text on the next view controller are updating, all ok. But if I will select Target 1 - opening next ViewController without any errors but labels text is empty nil.

I will appreciate if you help me or sudgest other way. I am simply using if else statement to check textField.

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let resultsVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController

        var declinationDegr = Int()
        if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 1"))! {
            declinationDegr = declinationDegreeTarget1
        } else if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 2"))! {
            declinationDegr = declinationDegreeTarget2
        }
        var declinationMinutes = Double()
        if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 1"))! {
            declinationMinutes = declinationMinutesTarget1
        } else if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 2"))! {
            declinationMinutes = declinationMinutesTarget2
        }
        var declinationDir = String()
        if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 1"))! {
            declinationDir = declinationDirTarget1
        } else if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 2"))! {
            declinationDir = declinationDirTarget2

resultsVC.bdeclString = "\(declinationDegr)º\(String(format: "%.1f", declinationMinutes))'\(declinationDir)"
  }
```

Comment: Could it be that you did not initialize the `target1` variables (like `declinationDegreeTarget1` etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you are missing the closing curly braces of the last if/else statement.

```
var declinationDir = String()
if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 1"))! {
    declinationDir = declinationDirTarget1
} else if (bodyTextField.text?.contains("Target 2"))! {
    declinationDir = declinationDirTarget2
} // CLOSING BRACE MISSING 

resultsVC.bdeclString = "\(declinationDegr)º\(String(format: "%.1f", declinationMinutes))'\(declinationDir)"
```

Second, I would re-organize the code a litte, to avoid unnecessary string comparison and forced unwrapping:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let resultsVC = segue.destination as? ResultsViewController  else {
        // error handling and
        return
    }
    guard let targetText = bodyTextField.text else {
        // error handling and
        return
    }

    var declinationDegr = Int()
    var declinationMinutes = Double()
    var declinationDir = String()

    if (targetText.contains("Target 1")) {
        declinationDegr = declinationDegreeTarget1
        declinationMinutes = declinationMinutesTarget1
        declinationDir = declinationDirTarget1
    } else if (targetText.contains("Target 2")) {
        declinationDegr = declinationDegreeTarget2
        declinationMinutes = declinationMinutesTarget2
        declinationDir = declinationDirTarget2
    } else {
        // error handling
    }

    resultsVC.bdeclString = "\(declinationDegr)º\(String(format: "%.1f", declinationMinutes))'\(declinationDir)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I just simply reorganized the code and it’s working.